# How to groupby/merge a data frame with various data types

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that has different data types (list, dictionary, list of dictionary, strings, etc).

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'category': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'House Targaryen'}],
  'connection': ['Rhaena Targaryen', 'Aegon Targaryen'],
  'description': 'Jon Snow, born Aegon Targaryen, is the son of Lyanna Stark '
                 'and Rhaegar Targaryen, the late Prince of Dragonstone',
  'name': 'Jon Snow'},
 {'category': [{'id': 2, 'name': 'House Stark'},
               {'id': 3, 'name': 'Nights Watch'}],
  'connection': ['Robb Stark', 'Sansa Stark', 'Arya Stark', 'Bran Stark'],
  'description': 'After successfully capturing a wight and presenting it to '
                 'the Lannisters as proof that the Army of the Dead are real, '
                 'Jon pledges himself and his army to Daenerys Targaryen.',
  'name': 'Jon Snow'}])
```

I want to merge these two rows by `Jon Snow` and combine all other fields together so it looks like

```
name                          category                                       description                                      connection

Jon Snow    ['House Targaryen','House Stark','Nights Watch'] Jon Snow, born ...... his army to Daenerys Targaryen.   ['Rhaena Targaryen',...,'Bran Stark']
```

It might be a little tricky with list of dictionaries, since this is a toy example, it only contains two rows, and it's easy to `explode` it and combine two rows of category together. But I don't think it's practical to do that in my actual data set.

I also thought about using `df.groupby('name').aggregate('category': func1,'description':func2, 'connection':func3)` but I'm not sure if there's a build-in function for what I need.

Thank yall for helping!

Comment: You can use a `groupby().apply()`

Comment: @pissall if you mean by ```groupby('name').apply(','.join)``` it will only combine the column names together since the data types are different

Comment: No, write a function assuming you will take a `df` of every group. Do any transformations you want on it and return the df. Apply this like `df.groupby("group_col").apply(func)`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your data, it might be possible to first do a simple `groupby` and `sum`. Then deal with the categories using list comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'category': [{'id': 1, 'name':'House Targaryen'}],
                    'name': 'Jon Snow',
                    'description':'Jon Snow, born Aegon Targaryen, is the son of Lyanna Stark and Rhaegar Targaryen, the late Prince of Dragonstone',
                    'connection':['Rhaena Targaryen', 'Aegon Targaryen']},
                   {'category': [{'id': 2, 'name': 'House Stark'},{'id': 3, 'name': 'Nights Watch'}],
                    'name': 'Jon Snow',
                    'description': 'After successfully capturing a wight and presenting it to the Lannisters as proof that the Army of the Dead are real, '
                                   'Jon pledges himself and his army to Daenerys Targaryen.',
                    'connection':['Robb Stark', 'Sansa Stark', 'Arya Stark', 'Bran Stark']},
                   {"category":[{"id":4,"name":"Some house"}],
                    "name": "Some name",
                    "description": "some desc",
                    "connection":["connection 1"]}])

result = df.groupby("name").sum()
result["category"] = [[item.get("name") for item in i] for i in result["category"]]
result.reset_index(inplace=True)

print (result)

#
            name                                      category                                        description                                         connection
0   Jon Snow  [House Targaryen, House Stark, Nights Watch]  Jon Snow, born Aegon Targaryen, is the son of ...  [Rhaena Targaryen, Aegon Targaryen, Robb Stark...
1  Some name                                  [Some house]                                          some desc                                     [connection 1]
```

Comment: I think it solves the example case, but I realize my df has missing values in pretty much all columns, and seems like ```sum()``` doesn't know to handle that